# Calculate dynamic price with many to many relationship using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relationship

I'm new to SQL and I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship. I know the math behind the calculation by am unable to transfer it into SQL language

Tables:

- Table A like:

| Item Name | Effective Date | Cancelled Date | Unit Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Book | 2010-01-02 | 2021-12-21 | 10 |
| Book | 2022-01-01 | 2028-01-01 | 15 |
| Ice Cream | 2018-01-01 | 2028-01-01 | 4 |

- Table B like:

| Item Name | Sales Date | Volume | Discounted Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Book | 2019-01-01 | 8 | 70 |
| Book | 2022-01-01 | 5 | 75 |
| Ice Cream | 2020-12-01 | 10 | 30 |

I want to calculate how much money each Item saved each month due to promotion, so my output should be:

| Item Name | Month | MoneySaved |
| --- | --- | --- |

I came up with the following structure:

```
select a.price as price_at_that_time 
from TableA join TableB on a.ItemName = b.ItemName
where SalesDate between EffectiveDate and CancelledDate
```

```
select to_char(SalesDate, 'YYYY-MM') as month,
     a.ItemName,
     sum(price_at_that_time * SalesVolume - discounted price) as MoneySaved
from TableA join TableB ...
group by to_char(SalesDate, 'YYYY-MM'),
    a.fitm
```

However, I'm not able to combine these two steps into one because of the many to many relationship and the dynamic nature of the price. Items may have different unit prices in different months, and even within a month, the unit price can be different.

I tired code like:

```
select to_char(SalesDate, 'YYYY-MM') as month,
     a.ItemName,
     sum(a.UnitPrice * SalesVolume - DiscountedPrice) as MoneySaved
from TableA join TableB on a.ItemName = b.ItemName
where a.UnitPrice in 
(select a.UnitPrice from TableA join TableB on a.ItemName = b.ItemName where SalesDate between EffectiveDate and CancelledDate) 
group by to_char(SalesDate, 'YYYY-MM'),
    a.fitm
```

I know the code is wrong but that's closest I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Almost exactly as you described it:

```
With TableA as (
    select *
    from (values 
     ('Book',   '2010-01-02',   '2021-12-21',   10)
    ,('Book',   '2022-01-01', '2028-01-01', 15)
    ,('Ice Cream',  '2018-01-01','2028-01-01',  4)
    ) T(ItemName,EffectiveDate,CancelledDate,   UnitPrice)
)
, TableB as (
select *
from (values 
 ('Book'    ,'2019-01-01'   ,8  ,70)
,('Book'    ,'2022-01-01'   ,5  ,75)
,('Ice Cream'   ,'2020-12-01'   ,10 ,30))
T(ItemName,SalesDate,Volume,DiscountedPrice)
)
select
      Sales.ItemName
    , sum((RegPRices.UnitPrice * Sales.Volume) - 
             Sales.DiscountedPrice) as SavedAmount
from 

   TableB as Sales

   inner join
   TableA RegPrices
   on RegPrices.ItemName=Sales.ItemName
    and Sales.SalesDate 
             between RegPrices.EffectiveDate and RegPrices.CancelledDate
group by Sales.ItemName
```

This returns:

| ItemName | SavedAmount |
| --- | --- |
| Book | 10 |
| Ice Cream | 10 |

.